# MongoDB query returns "Error: Invalid JSON object" on valid query

Tags: r, json, mongodb, mongolite

### Issue

I have probably mucked up the syntax for the JSON query, but cannot for the life of me see where. Trying to create data.frame overviewData grouped on four values with an extra COUNT-feature.

### Code

```
overviewData <- M_CONNECTION$aggregate('[
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "Hotel_Name" : "$Hotel_Name", 
                    "lat" : "$lat", 
                    "lng" : "$lng", 
                    "Average_Score" : "$Average_Score"
                }, 
                "COUNT(Hotel_Name)" : {
                    "$sum" : NumberInt(1)
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "Hotel_Name" : "$_id.Hotel_Name", 
                "lat" : "$_id.lat", 
                "lng" : "$_id.lng", 
                "Average_Score" : "$_id.Average_Score", 
                "COUNT(Hotel_Name)" : "$COUNT(Hotel_Name)", 
                "_id" : NumberInt(0)
            }
        }
    ]',
options = '{"allowDiskUse" : true}'
)
```

I have quotes around all of my queries, as well as around the options. Still getting an "Invalid JSON object"-error message.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not sure, I guess this line is causing you trouble ->

```
"$sum" : NumberInt(1)
```

Instead of this, please try this ->

```
"$sum" : 1
```

Kindly try this and let me know if this helped.

Comment: This did not solve my issue, but I will just be executing the query inside of Studio 3T. Thank you for your reply in any case!

Comment: Why didn't it solve it? Are you seeing the same error message? From pure JSON point of view, `$sum: NumberInt(1)` is not valid, since the value of JSON field can only be a string, an object, a number, or an array. `NumberInt(1)` is a function, which is not valid.

Comment: Did you remove this part in $project stage as well -> "_id : NumberInt(0)" ?